# Deploying a spring boot war on jetty9.4.6 with no URI in the war available

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, war

I follow the spring boot reference document to make an executable and deployable war in 2 steps:

1. in pom file, make a war package and make spring-boot-starter-tomcat scope
   provided
2. make the Application class extends
   SpringBootServletInitializer and override configure method.

then copy the war file to {jetty_home}/webapps.

I tried restart the jetty server and it seems the war was loaded with below info

```
2017-07-24 11:16:35.740:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6e1ec318{/abc-0.1,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-abc-0.1.war-_abc-0.1-any-4452702112804908874.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/abc-0.1.war}
```

Visitin {jetty_server_ip}:8080/abc-0.1 shows "Directory: /abc-0.1/" while visit any URL in the war returns a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong? Please guide.

Comment: I use a tomcat server instead of jetty server and everything goes fine. any hint why jetty failed?

Comment: here the current status, I checked with both embedded server and standalone server composition and it seems that a)the war with an embedded tomcat server works on a standalone tomcat server; b)the war with an embedded tomcat server doesn't work with a standalone jetty server; c)the war with an embedded jetty server doesn't work with a standalone tomcat/jetty server

Answer (score 0):

The WebApp's "context path" is set to `/abc-0.1` in your deployed instance.

You will only be able to access that webapp on `{host}/abc-0.1/`.

Assuming that you have no other contexts (webapps) deployed, then you have nothing answering at `{host}/abc/` and will always get 404 for `{host}/abc/` prefixed URLs.

Comment: sorry, my fault to miss "-0.1" in the original post. edited.